# Bootstrap Datetimepicker not recognized by MVC application

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker

I am trying to include bootstrap datetimepicker into my MVC application but my project does not seem to recognize it.

I first downloaded the `Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.css` nuget package which downloadad all necessary dependencies required for the utility.

As per my research the following is required to run datetimepicker:

- bootstrap
- moment-with-locales
- bootstrap-datetimepicker
- bootstrap-datetimepicker

After the installation I modified the following in my `BundleConfig.cs` file:

First including the css file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/Content/datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                        ........
                        ));
```

Then added a couple of bundles to include the JS files required:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datetimepicker").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js",       
                        "~/Scripts/moment.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"));
```

I included the following into my `_Layout.cshtml` file :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Lastly, in my view where I am wanting to actually call the datetimepicker, I have the following script:

```
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker");
    <script>

        $('.input-group.date').datetimepicker();

    </script>
}
```

I have never had a problem like this in the past. I use the bootstrap **DATEPICKER** fairly regularly in other parts of my application doing the exact same architecture and it works just fine.

My application does nothing to recognize the additions the the project. My scripting block in my view even recognizes the old datepicker in the intellisense but not datetimepicker.

Comment: Can you share any errors from the script console in your browser? This is potentially down to the ordering (although you didn't mention where your bundles are placed in the layout file). If your `Scripts` section is rendering before your bundles in the layout file, it is likely that the date picker is failing to find its dependencies at the time you use it.

Comment: @Sohnee you were exactly correct. Moment was required to be loaded before bootstrap. I moved my `@Scripts.render("~/bundles/moment")` to my view and rendered it right before I did the datetimepicker and it works. I am still a little confused though. My bundles are being rendered in the head of my layout file. My `Scripts` is at the bottom of my view.... I take it the script's section comes before the layout header section?

Comment: Also, @Sohnee if you would like to post an answer I will gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is potentially down to the ordering (although you didn't mention where your bundles are placed in the layout file).

If your Scripts section is rendering before your bundles in the layout file, it is likely that the date picker is failing to find its dependencies at the time you use it.

For example, this might cause a problem:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

But this should work...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```